# How to clear a combo box's "Selected Item" VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, controls

I am having a problem clearing the selected item of my combo box.
I have looked around and apparently the go to option is normally 
"box.SelectedItem = -1" however for my code it only seems to break it.

```
    Dim cat2Name As String = cat2Box.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim listName = "cat3Box"


    cat3Box.SelectedIndex = -1
    cat3Box.Items.Clear()

    Call changeCatBox(cat2Name, listName)
```

This piece of code is suppose to clear everything inside of a 3rd box but it breaks the program. Any help is appreciated

Comment: _breaks the program_ is not an accurate description of the error. Please report the exact error message received and in which line this happens

Comment: `Call` is sooo 1980s

Comment: why are you doing "cat3Box.Items.Clear()" this command will remove all the items you have in the combo box...., just remove it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear a selected item,
try this

```
 If Not ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Remove(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
        ComboBox1.Update()
    Else
        ''NOTHING
    End If
```

I'm not too sure how you want to execute this, but this should help you along your way.

P.S I am just using "ComboBox1" by default, just to make it clear for you :)

Comment: It will me much faster to do "ComboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)", and you need to check if ComboBox1.SelectedItem is not nothing (or if ComboBox1.SelectedIndex is not -1)